# How to integrate Paypal with SOAP API?

Tags: soap, paypal, paypal-soap

I have some problem when i integrate PayPal with SOAP API.

Now, This my code

```
// Set paypal
// Include NuSOAP
$url_nusoap                 = "xxx/nusoap/nusoap.php";
include($url_nusoap);

$wsdl_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl";
$s_URL  = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/";
$s_Ver  = "94.0";

$header = "";
$header .= "<RequesterCredentials xmlns='urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI' xsi:type='ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType'>";
$header .= "<Credentials xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' xsi:type='ebl:UserIdPasswordType'>";
$header .= "<Username>@api_username@</Username>";
$header .= "<Password>@api_password@</Password>";
$header .= "<Signature>@api_signature@</Signature>";
$header .= "</Credentials>";
$header .= "</RequesterCredentials>";

$s  = new soap_client($wsdl_URL, true);
$err = $s->getError();
if ($err) die("Soap client constructor err.. check wsdl url");

//set end point
$s->setEndpoint($s_URL);

$s->setHeaders($header);

$bodyReq = "?"
$result = $s->call("?", $bodyReq);
```

And my problem is i don't know what should i call API in "$bodyReq" and $s->call(); ?
This my situation :
In my site can select pay method

1. Paypal
2. xxx
3. xxx

When i choose "1 Paypal" and submit - Redirect to "pay_checker" if pay_method == "Paypal" redirect to "PAYPAL SOAP API Page" (if pay_method == "xxx" redirect it to some API in other pay services)

I need if i select "PayPal method" and redirect to "PAYPAL SOAP API" page it's call some API to pass $amount ,$product_name and redirect to PAYPAL Billing page

somebody help me please

Thank you.

Edit ------ Now i learn "ExpressCheckout" but i don't know where point to learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you currently have is building your credentials only, which would then get included in your actual XML request, which is where $bodyReq would come into play.

PayPal provides plenty of [documentation for Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec), including [this document specific to the SOAP API](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_api_reference.pdf).  Chapter 6 covers Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks man, Finally i used Express Checkout (Set ,Get ,Do) and it's ok! i can used SOAP and XML redirect to billing page instead "paypal button"

thank for your suggestion